# helm: find-file it is possible to ignore `[?] ...` during iteration

Tags: helm

I am using `helm` when I am using Find Files (`ctrl+c ctrl+f`)

```
(require 'helm)
(require 'helm-config)

(define-key helm-map (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-next-line) ; rebind tab to run persistent action
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-i") 'helm-next-line) ; make TAB work in terminal
```

[image]

---

When I type and press `TAB` for `helm-next-line`, I want helm to iterate over the found files like `update_repo.sh` and `update_local_configuration.sh` on the given example. But in addition it also always iterates over `[?] update_` which I do not want. Is it possible to obtain this?

Comment: That's for creating new file, you need it, otherwise you won't be able to create new file which is a necessary functionality of helm-find-files.

Comment: That can remain as it is but when I press `TAB` can it only iterate in between the find files like it does on the linux terminals. If I want to create new file I can go into `?` line and press enter